# How to debug iPhone X simulator from safari?

Tags: safari, frontend, mobile-safari, iphone-x, safari-web-inspector

I'm trying to debug `iPhone X` simulator from safari, so that I can adjust my CSS. But it doesn't appear under `Develop toolbar`. Where on other hand `iPhone 7` simulator appears. Web inspector is enabled on both devices. On Safari Technical Preview I have the same issue.

Perhaps anyone knows how can I make iPhone X simulator to appear in `Develop toolbar`?

[image: Screen-Shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that OSX version has to be updated to `High Sierra Beta 10.31.1`

Answer (score 3):

Try restarting Safari while keeping your simulator open. That did the trick for me.